# Mozilla Thunderbird Inbox folder: remove specific dated messages

Tags: thunderbird

It appears that Tools / Message Filters only work on incoming messages. Once the message is in the Inbox folder (or any other folder for that matter) then Message Filters play no further part. I get specific messages with offers valid for, say, 14 days. Eventually the messages become outdated and I have to remove them by hand. I want Thunderbird to look into the Inbox folder and run a Message Filter to clean out the specific messages that are older than 14 days and to do this each time I look for new mail from the server.

I am not talking about **incoming** messages that are outdated by 14 days. I am talking about **specific messages** that have **arrived** and have been sitting in the Inbox folder for more than 14 days.

Any suggestions??

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to have a rule that puts these messages into a single folder, then set the retention on that folder to 14 days.

This way the whole process is automatic.

To set retention on a folder, right click, select properties, and go into the Retention Policy tab.

Note that you can run the rule on the inbox when you have created it, so this will also clean up any existing messages.

If you have different messages with different retention requirements, use multiple rules with multiple folders, each with their own policy.

Comment: Paul: Thanks for your prompt reply. I was trying to avoid this solution and stay in the opening Inbox. The annoying thing is if I open the Message Filter dialogue box and press the 'Run Now' button it does exactly what I want. But I can't get it to do it automatically. Thanks once again